# Add active class to an element onclick just for the duration of click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add active class to an element when someone clicks on it and then auto remove it immediately.

I've already tried with below methods but no luck yet -

Method - 1

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.classname').on('click', function() {
        $('.classname').addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Method - 2

```
$('.classname').on('click', function() {
    $( ".classname" ).switchClass( "active", "no-active", 1000 );
});
```

Comment: Do you want to add class when the mouse is being pressed?? Is that what you want?? If so, you can use 'onmousedown' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you need to use `setTimeout()`, however the logic is a little off.

Firstly you need to use `setTimeout()` *within* the click handler. You will then need to call `removeClass()` on a reference to the clicked element when the timer completes. Try this:

```js
$('.classname').on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this).addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $el.removeClass('active');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  transition: color 0.3s, background-color 0.5s;
}
.active { 
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #C00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classname">foo</div>
<div class="classname">foo</div>
<div class="classname">foo</div>
<div class="classname">foo</div>
<div class="classname">foo</div>
```

However, from the image you posted it looks like all you may need is to add an `:active` state. This is applied to the element while the mouse button is held down on it:

```css
div:active {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is is better to be done with just CSS:
using `:active` so it will be something like this:

```css
button {
    background-color:red;
}

button:active {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
Click Here
</button>
```

or with a little delay:

```css
button {
    border: 1px solid #bada55;
    background-color:red;
    transition: .50s all;   
    transition-delay: 1s; 
}

button:active {
    background-color:green;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
Click Here
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

before `setTimeout` function call you add the `class` and after some seconds it will remove using `settimeout`

```js
$('.classname').click(function() {
  $('.classname').addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.classname').removeClass('active');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.active {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classname">
  test
</div>
```

and for `switchclass`

You are missing jQuery UI most likely, as switchClass is part of jQuery UI, and not the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.classname').addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.classname').removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="classname">Hello</div>
```

try this one